# Is it ok to user a "spacer.gif" in a container with a background image to apply alt text to that background image

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, wai-aria

I have a background image in my header area of my site.  It's done as a background image for responsive design purposes.  I would like however for screen readers to be able to read some information about that area (company info).

I have placed a spacer.gif (ya know...what we used to use in the old days of tabular layouts :) ) in that container and added alt text to it so screen readers will still be able to provide good accessibility.

I haven't found anything that says this is "ok" so I'm wondering about good practice or not.  That being said, I also haven't found anything that says it's not good practice "not ok".

Can anyone shed some light here?
TIA

EDIT:  I ended up using my own suggestion as I didn't get any feedback to tell me it was a bad idea.  I will mark isherwood's answer as the answer because it is certainly a viable alternative.

here's what I did:

```
        <div id="headerImage">
            <img src="~/Content/images/spacer.gif" alt="Widgets For Sale Here At This Widget Store" />
        </div>
```

where #headerImage contains the CSS to place my banner image as a background image.

Comment: Show your code and explain what you regard as a potential problem there. Note that asking about “good practice” tends to be primarily opinion-based, hence off-topic at SO; so make sure you are asking a question that is answerable on a solid technical basis.

Comment: @Jukka, I would question whether it is right to treat matters of good practice as off topic. Obviously questions such as "which is the best browser" are opinion based and off topic, but we should all be encouraging good practice (where clearly accepted by the industry as such). And we should teach good practice by answering questions on it. To show what can go wrong if we don't, witness all the answers to CSS questions on StackOverflow that say "use !important". That may be techically accurate, but it is generally agreed in the industry as just about the worst thing to do in CSS practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably a valid option, but it adds markup and the need to deal with another image file.

I would use an offscreen text element at the start of the element having the background image:

```
.offscreen {position: absolute; left: -999em;}

<div class="header-with-css-background">  
    <span class="offscreen">Information about the image here</span>
    Other header content
</div>
```

You'll probably find that having such a class available proves helpful in a number of situations, such as when a form should have a label but you don't want to show it to sighted users because you have placeholder text on the input.

Comment: I read about that as an option and just using an ARIA attribute.  I actually like my approach better and I guess my question is more around, is that good practice or not.  If not, why not?

Comment: I mentioned why not in my opening sentence. I don't believe there are any more serious downsides.

Comment: the amount of markup difference between your solution and mine is negligible and the image file is only 43 bytes so no biggy there either.  I think I'll run with it unless someone else can give me a compelling reason as to why not.

Answer (score -1):

If you want screen readers to glean info about your company, add that to the alt tag for the background image. 
According to the W3.org page, if an image is the only content of a link or form control, " Use the alt attribute communicate the destination of the link or action taken."

[Follow this link to more complete discussion of best practices for use of alt tag in web pages, at w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/html5/alt-techniques/)

Comment: A background image (applied with CSS) cannot have an alt attribute.

Comment: It is less a case of they 'cannot' than they usually 'do not' because a background image is usually just eye candy. OP said he wants screen readers to provide company info in a nearby spacer. Since the alt tag will contain more than just a meaningless "this is an image" message," it would make sense just to add that info in the backround image alt tag.

Comment: No, you don't understand. One can not use alt text on an element other than an image, and no image tag exists in this case.

Comment: isherwood, you are correct about no alt tag. my bad. but you can still add the alternative tag, using the title attribute, as follows:

    <div class="company_info" title="put the company info here, in the title"></div>
CSS

    .company_info {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background: url(~/images/super_duper_background_image.png) -50px 0;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }

obviously, the pixel values are arbitrary and only present for example sake

Comment: true, it is not ideal, but he was asking if it was 'ok' to associate company info with the page background image. Since the W3C signs off on the practice, I guess my point is, "go ahead and do it." If he uses title on background image or alt tag on spacer image is immaterial. 
I leave the implementation to him; I only mean to answer his question about best practice by saying, 'go for it. the interweb style police will not come down on you for that.'

Comment: The `title` attribute is not reliably announced by assistive technology. Do not use it to convey essential information.